# Splicer.dll on Windows 2008

Tags: directshow

I'm attempting to leverage the splicer.dll component from http://splicer.codeplex.com on a windows 2008 server.  I'm running into an error when the splicer.dll is first used.  I'm guessing I don't have one of the dependencies installed.  What are the required components that I need?

Error:

Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {78530B75-61F9-11D2-8CAD-00A024580902} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at Splicer.Timeline.DefaultTimeline..ctor(Double fps, String temporaryStoragePath)

Further investigation leads me to believe it's related to qedit.dll which isn't installed and can't be copied and registered from my Win7 machine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that Windows 2008 doesn't have the components necessary to leverage the splicer.dll installed by default.  I simply added the "Desktop Experience" Feature to my installation and the appropriate COM DLLs were installed.

Answer (score 1):

Though you clearly are missing a COM DLL, you should try out Depends.Net:

http://www.netomatix.com/Development/DependsNet.aspx

It will give you an idea what the missing component is.

My instincts are you may want to install the latest DirectX runtime.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3

In addition, you may want to make sure you have the latest version of drivers for your video card.

Comment: I tried installing the latest DirectX and the video card drivers are up to date.  Same result.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you look at the Depends.NET output?  It will certainly spell out the missing dependency.  In addition, if you find it to be a COM DLL you could use old fashioned depends as perhaps what's really missing in a pure DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Class Not Registered (HRESULT 0x80040154), means that your program requested to instantiate a COM object that isn't registered in the registry (e.g. installed on your computer).

In DirectShow, filters are implemented as COM objects and must be registered on the local machine (with regsvr32) before they can be used.

Are you trying to playback a media file?  If this is the case, the media file type requires a codec installed that understands that media type.

If you're not sure what's going on, you might try installing the k-lite codec pack, which'll include codecs for many video and audio formats which may be missing from your computer.

Good luck!